# How to update a single row/item on an observable array from edit modal?

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observable array "users" that is just basically a grid when displayed.  The user will click on the link of the LoginId which will open up a model to edit the single user (First Name, Last Name, plus more that is not on the grid view, etc). If the user changes the FirstName on the edit modal, I want it to reflect on the grid after a successful save.  I have seen two approaches:  find using arrayFirst and remove/re-add user to grid or making each item in the observable array observable.  I'm not sure what is the best approach to get this to work and how to properly set up the observable array observable if that is the best way to do it.

```
function UserViewModel() {    

                var self = this;

                //data which is populated on a load AJAX function => self.users(msg.d);
                self.users = ko.observableArray([]);                   

                self.updateUser = function () {
                    //set edit modal elements
                    self.editFirstName(this.FirstName);
                    //set the rest for edit
                    //open modal, user edits 'editFirstName' and hits save
                    //data saved to DB
                    //now I want to update the FirstName the user edited in the users array so I don't have to repull all users in the grid

                   }
```

}

HTML fragment

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: users">
            <tr>
                <td class="border-left"><a href="#"  data-bind="text: LoginId,click: $parent.updateUser"/></td>
                <td data-bind="text: FirstName"/>
                <td data-bind="text: LastName"/>
                <td data-bind="text: EmailAddress"/>
                <td data-bind="text: AccessLevel"/>                  
                <td data-bind="text: Status" class="border-right" />
            </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the table to update when the values are changed, the properties that the table binds to need to be `observables`. You didn't post your `User` class, so I don't know if this is the case, but it should look something like this:

```
var Person = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.loginId = data.loginId;
    self.firstName = ko.observable(data.firstName);
    self.lastName = ko.observable(data.lastName);
    self.emailAddress = ko.observable(data.emailAddress);
    self.accessLevel = ko.observable(data.accessLevel);
    self.status = ko.observable(data.status);
};
```

When you change these values, the table should update. Check it out in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9D36/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and easy to understand fiddle.  I was missing the arrayMap step in a version I tried before finally submitting my question.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about this basic point. I knew it, forgot, re-discovered it and forgot it again. Thanks also for the reminder of the arrayMap. It's in the Knockout examples but I don't think it's actually documented.